# Быстрый поиск изображений внутри изображения попиксельно

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, pillow

Мне нужно найти в изображении другое изображение за минимальное время (вывести их координаты) на Python. Если это изображение встречается несколько раз, то надо найти их все. Желательно использовать PIL.

Я нашёл пару кодов, выполняющих это... Но мне нужна **максимально возможная скорость**, чего не дают те программы.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18075751/14775762

Answer (score 1):

Результатом выполнения программы будут координаты всех вхождений изображения needle в изображение haystack с порогом совпадения threshold.

```
import cv2 #pip install opencv-python
import numpy as np

haystack = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
needle = cv2.imread('2.jpg')

# Выполняем поиск совпадений
result = cv2.matchTemplate(haystack, needle, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

# Определяем порог совпадения
threshold = 0.8

# Получаем координаты всех совпадений
locations = []
for y, x in zip(*np.where(result >= threshold)):
    locations.append((x, y))

# Выводим координаты совпадений
print('Совпадение на координатах:', locations)
```

Comment: Подправил код :)

Comment: Спасибо! Возможно, есть варианты быстрее и/или на PIL, так что посмотрю ещё, если кто-то напишет :)

Comment: а можно исправить, что ответ полезен или хотя бы нейтрален ?  :)
заранее спасибо  :)

Comment: Да, интересно, кто минус поставил и за что?

Comment: Если не нужен порог совпадения, то можно его убрать, будет быстрее. Также [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29669787/8489602) довольно быстрый код, но не PIL.

Comment: @DiMithras мне приходится загружать изображение через PIL, как-то переводить в cv2 и использовать np.atleast_3d... Получилось долго.
И как убрать threshold? Поставить на единицу?

Comment: @Артём тогда понятно почему PIL. Да, в единицу.